# How do I get my create action to work for both a nested & non-nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, nested-resources

So I have two models `Topic`, `Client`. A Client `has_and_belongs_to_many :topics`, and a Topic `has_and_belongs_to_many :clients`.

Basically, what I want to happen is...when someone goes to my `Topic#index`, depending on how they got there (i.e. either via `client/:id/topics` or just `/topics`), I want the behavior of the create & new to be different. i.e. at `/topics`, it just creates a topic. At `client/:id/topics` it creates a topic and assigns it to that client.

My routes look like this:

```
  resources :topics
  resources :clients do
    resources :topics
  end
```

My Topics Controller looks like this:

```
  def new
        if params[:client_id]
            @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
            @topic = @client.topics.build
        else
            @topic = Topic.new
        end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @topic }
    end
  end

  def create
        if params[:client_id]
            @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
            @topic = @client.topics.build(params[:topic])
        else
        @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
        end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @topic, status: :created, location: @topic }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My `views/topics/_form.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@client, @topic]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

However, when I perform an action from `client/:id/topics` this is what the logs look like:

```
Started GET "/clients/1/topics/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-10 14:33:06 -0500
Processing by TopicsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"client_id"=>"1"}
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered topics/_form.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered topics/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 57.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

That looks good...everything seems to be in order here. But it is in the `POST` that things seem to be not working:

```
Started POST "/clients/1/topics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-10 14:33:13 -0500
Processing by TopicsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J172LuZQPv8=", "topic"=>{"name"=>"AMZN"}, "commit"=>"Create Topic", "client_id"=>"1"}
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (186.2ms)  INSERT INTO "topics" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 10 Sep 2012 19:33:13 UTC +00:00], ["name", "AMZN"], ["updated_at", Mon, 10 Sep 2012 19:33:13 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/topics/4
Completed 302 Found in 198ms (ActiveRecord: 191.1ms)
```

You will notice there is no assignment of the new topic to the client.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

Added puts debug statements to my create action, and this is the result I got after the POST action was executed - which indicates that is getting the `params[:client_id]` and not just `params[:id]`:

```
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
**************************************************
This is the params[:client_id] => {3}
**************************************************
This is the params[:id] => {}


Started POST "/clients/3/topics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-10 15:06:31 -0500
Processing by TopicsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J172LuZQc5NYoiMSzDD3oY9vGmxxCX0OdxcGm4GSPv8=", "topic"=>{"name"=>"TEST2"}, "commit"=>"Create Topic", "client_id"=>"3"}
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "topics" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 10 Sep 2012 20:06:31 UTC +00:00], ["name", "TEST2"], ["updated_at", Mon, 10 Sep 2012 20:06:31 UTC +00:00]]
   (3.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/topics/6
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

**Edit 2:**

So I tried something else that seems to work, but I would love to know why the above doesn't work.

If, in my `Topic#create` I just do this:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
@topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
@client.topics << @topic
```

It works fine.

But, again...I would love to know why the `.build` doesn't for HABTM or in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the `params[:client_id]` it may be `params[:id]`.

Can you put a `puts` statement in your if else block of create action, and then see which one is showing up when you hit the page(create a topic)

**EDIT**

You need to include **accepts_nested_attributes_for** in your model to support dynamic building of nested object attributes.

Refer [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: That's not the issue. I updated the question to include that output.

Comment: Also, in my log output I included in the question, you can see that it is finding the correct `params[:client_id]` and including it in the params hash correctly. It's just not doing the correct thing with it.

Comment: hmm... seems pretty strange after your Edit2 ....

can you try once the steps written in your old create method in rails console.. and see what the actual issue is...

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to explicitly call save after the build is done on my `@client` object.

Otherwise, ActiveRecord won't save the transaction and insert a new record in the join_table.